# How to merge two different code results in R in the same output file

Tags: r, output

I have to combine the results of following two codes using a single program -

```
Book1 <- read.csv("Book1.csv" , header = FALSE) 
Book2 <- read.csv("Book2.csv" , header = FALSE)
Book3 <- read.csv("Book3.csv" , header = FALSE)

sink("output.txt")
for (i in seq(1,3)) {
  for (j in seq(2,5)) {
    if(Book1[i,j]==1 & Book2[i,j]==2 & Book3[i,j]==1)
      print(1) 
    else
      print(0)

   } 
}
sink()
```

Now, in the second code everything else is same except the condition inside `if` which is `Book1[i,j]==2 & Book2[i,j]==2 & Book3[i,j]==4`. I am running these two codes separately and getting two output text files. How can I run the two codes together and get the output in the same text file. The output should be looking like this in a single text file without any `[1]` in the beginning -

```
  0 0
  0 0 
  0 0
  0 0
  0 1 
  0 0
  0 0
  1 0
  0 0
  0 0
  0 0 
  0 0
```

I tried using **concatenation** command but always got an error. And here is the result for `deput()` -

```
> dput(head(Book1))
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L), V2 = c(3L, 2L, 6L, 3L), 
V3 = c(7L, 3L, 5L, 5L), V4 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), V5 = c(7L, 
1L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names =c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")


> dput(head(Book2))
structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 6L), V2 = c(6L, 2L, 6L, 3L), 
V3 = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 5L), V4 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), V5 = c(7L, 
2L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(Book3))
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L), V2 = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 3L), 
V3 = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 2L), V4 = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 1L), V5 = c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the input data as well. You can [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance. Also, it looks like you want the outputs to be concatenated column-wise. Is that so?

Comment: @Aramis7d Yes and sorry but the link directs me to a 'page not found' page.

Comment: could you look into `cbind()`? to combine all Book's together

Comment: @Dark_Knight weird. try http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . 
Also, are you confident of all individual outputs being of the same length?

Comment: @Aramis7d Yes, all individual outputs are of same length. The loop runs for equal no. of time for each code.

Comment: You do not need loops at all. `sink`ing `print`ed values is not how we do such things in R. I'd show you how you can do this very simply if you only provided the output of `dput(head(...))` for your `Book1` to `Book3`.

Comment: @Roland I have made the edit in question. This data is a small subset for a very large size actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write a vectorized function:

```
fun <- function(a, b, c) {
  #calculate the combinations of i and j values
  #and use them for vectorized subsetting
  inds <- as.matrix(expand.grid(2:5, 1:3))[, 2:1]

  #vectorized comparisons
  as.integer((Book1[inds] == a & 
              Book2[inds] == b & 
              Book3[inds] == c)) 
}

res <- cbind(fun(1, 2, 1),
             fun(2, 2, 4))

#export the result
write.table(res, "test.txt", sep = "\t", 
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE)
#0  0
#0  0
#0  0
#0  0
#0  1
#0  0
#0  0
#1  0
#0  0
#0  0
#0  0
#0  0
```

Comment: What does `[, 2:1]` do?

Comment: Study `help("[")`. It switches the columns.